# Php fetch Data from MLXCHANGE Listings

Tags: php, wordpress, executefetchrequest

I want to fetch listings from:

mlxchange.com site which is a platform for realestate agent's, i am working on a project in Wordpress and i want to fetch the listings from this site, i have all credential's of user.

we can sign in from here:

http://idp.mfrmls.safemls.net/idp/Authn/UserPassword

How can i fetch data from his listing, i have searched for api by this mls services provider but didn't find any thing..

Thanks for your help, I am working with Wordpress thanks again....

Comment: If they don't have an API then it'll need to be hard coded, steal a login cookie then scrape the data with something like simple php dom parser

Comment: It's called an `IDX` that supplies the data. [here's a bit of info from that provider](http://mfrmls.com/member-support/mls-technology/idx-faqs#Q1)